# Are custom Steam URLs reusable?

Tags: steam

Let's say I have `http://steamcommunity.com/id/xyz` as my custom URL on Steam and then I change it to `http://steamcommunity.com/id/qrs`.

Is `xyz` now available for someone else to claim as their URL slug? (And if not, then can *I* go back to `xyz` at a later date?)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that URL should be useable. When you want to set a custom URL it tells you if the URL is free or not. After you change to another URL the old one is free.